# Delete files from SFTP using R Studio

Tags: r

I need to delete files from an FTP site once I have processed them in R (parsing content). However, nothing I try seems to work.

this is what ive trying, and variations of.

```
library(RCurl)

curlPerform(url="sftp://user:password@sftplocation/folder/", quote="DELE filename.pdf")

curlPerform(url="ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/", quote="DELE file.txt", userpwd = "user:pass")
```

Error is 
    Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Unknown SFTP command

When I run the following code, I get a lovely list of all the files (which is used to download them). So I know the connection is working just great, and the parsing from the downloaded files works great!

```
curlPerform(url="sftp://user:password@sftplocation/folder/")
```

Thanks,
Siobhan

Comment: How doesn't it work? Error message? No error message but file not deleted?

Comment: Is this `curlPerform` from the `RCurl` package? You should always specify the packages you use in examples here.

Comment: Ah, sorry, im new to this! Yes this is utilising RCurl. The error im getting is;                                          Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Unknown SFTP command

Comment: @Siobhan Welcome at stackoverflow! Please mark an answer as "accepted" if it solves your problem described in the question to give others the chance to find good answers quickly. Thx :-)

Answer (score 2):

To delete over `sftp`, use `rm` instead of `DELE` - which looks like an `ftp` rather than an `sftp` command.

Then make sure you have the full file path. This works for me:

```
curlPerform(
 url="sftp://me@host.example.com/", 
.opts=list(
   ssh.public.keyfile=pub,
   ssh.private.keyfile=pri),
   verbose=TRUE,
   quote="rm  /home/me/test/test.txt")
```

Note I've put my credentials in some key files so I don't put the password in plain text in the code.

I'm not convinced this is the best way to do it, since I can't stop it printing the contents of the URL... There's might be an option...

Comment: Andrie de Vries and Gábor Csárdi have presented a new package `secret` for storing credentials (useR!2017: "Can you keep a secret?"): https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conferences/useR-International-R-User-2017-Conference/Can-you-keep-a-secret

Comment: Thanks Spacedman. This gets me so close I can smell success! Is there anyway to run this without using keyfiles? As this is an internal app and an internal ftp site we should be ok with the details passed in plain text...oh and I have no idea how to create the keyfiles on redhat!!

Comment: So the code I now have is this and im getting No such file or directory error, which is massive progress! Ive played with the structure of the filename etc to no avail! for (d in pdfs_to_run)
                                                                                                                 {
      curlPerform(
         url="sftp://usr:pwd@sftp/",
         quote=paste0("rm  /foldername/",filename[d])
       )
      }

Comment: Are the files really in `/foldername/`, because that's the very top of the system files. Can you log in to the remote machine and see if things are being deleted? Can you simplify and test outside the loop with an example that doesn't involve constructing a path with `paste` etc?